# How can I make dot in calculator app to use once in a number

Tags: ios, swift, floating-point, uilabel, calculator

I have a problem with my calculator app (which is done from the course). App is finished but at the end of a day when I press the number, then dot for decimal places and again dot app crashes. Also when you press the dot before the number the label changes from "0" to just "." and when you try to do it again, app crashes as well. Here's code where problem occurs:

```
@IBOutlet weak var displayLabel: UILabel!
    
    private var calculator = CalculatorLogic()
    
    private var isFinishedTypingNumber: Bool = true
    private var displayValue: Double {
        get {
            guard let number = Double(displayLabel.text!) else {
                fatalError("Cannot convert display label text to a Double")
            }
            return number
        }
        set {
            displayLabel.text = String(newValue)
        }
    }
```

And this is code with calculations:

```
@IBAction func numButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        //What should happen when a number is entered into the keypad
        
        if let numValue = sender.currentTitle {
            
            if isFinishedTypingNumber {
                displayLabel.text = numValue
                isFinishedTypingNumber = false
                
            } else {
                
                if numValue == "." {
                    
                    let isInt = floor(displayValue) == displayValue
                    if !isInt {
                        return
                    }
                    
                }
                
                displayLabel.text = displayLabel.text! + numValue
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

To summarize: problem occurs whenever I press the second dot, it's fine like this "1.23" etc., it crashes when it's like this ".." or "1.2."

It crashes where the fatalError is, I know I need to do changes there and I tried to make 'guard let' with just 'if let' but it didn't work as I expected: creating if let wants me to return a Double which I can't do. I couldn't add if statement into else brackets too.

Comment: update ```if !isInt``` with  ```if !isInt || displayLabel.text!.contains(".")```

Comment: @udi worked for numbers case, it stoped to put dot after dot was used, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found a solution:

In order to get rid of double dot crash I've added an if statement to `@IBAction func numButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton)` to check there if there's a dot:

```
if isFinishedTypingNumber {

            if numValue == "." {
                displayLabel.text = "0."
            } else {
                displayLabel.text = numValue
            }
            
            isFinishedTypingNumber = false
```

To get rid of second crash I've added `if !isInt || displayLabel.text!.contains(".")`, thank you @udi!